# Почему заменяется первая буква в названии класса Yii2

Tags: yii2

Хочу включить панель отладки, пишу так:

```
$config['modules']['debug'] = 'yii\debug\Module';
$config['modules']['debug']['allowedIPs'] = ['*'];
```

На что мне отвечает

```
Class Aii\debug\Module does not exist
```

Почему оно меняет первую букву? Даже если я напишу так

```
$config['modules']['debug'] = 'nanana';
$config['modules']['debug']['allowedIPs'] = ['*'];
```

оно скажет

```
Class Aanana does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

Вся проблема была в том, что не верно были прописаны настройки. Надо было писать не

```
$config['modules']['debug'] = 'yii\debug\Module';
$config['modules']['debug']['allowedIPs'] = ['*'];
```

а

```
$config['modules']['debug'] = [
    'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
    'allowedIPs' => ['*'],
];
```